# DXGI got an error in func Map "Access Violation"

Tags: c++, video, compiler-errors, directx, dxgi

Good afternoon, I am writing a program that will extract pixels from the desktop, but unfortunately I ran into a problem, Map gives an error "Access Violation". Help me please.

I've divided all the code by function to make it clear to you.
I hope you can help me because I have little experience with directx and dxgi so far.

```
ID3D11Device *m_pDevice;
ID3D11DeviceContext *m_pDeviceContext;
IDXGIDevice *m_pDXGIDevice;
ID3D11Texture2D* m_pDesktopTexture;
ID3D11Texture2D* m_pCompatibleTexture;
//ID3D11Device* m_pDevice;
IDXGIAdapter* m_pDXGIAdapter;
IDXGIOutput* m_pDXGIOutput;
IDXGIOutput1* m_pDXGIOutput1;
IDXGIOutputDuplication* m_pOutputDuplication = nullptr;
DXGI_OUTDUPL_DESC m_OutputDuplicationDescription;
DXGI_OUTPUT_DESC m_OutputDescription;
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE m_mappedResource;

HRESULT CreateD3DDevice()
{
HRESULT hResult = S_OK;

D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevel = D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1;

hResult = D3D11CreateDevice(nullptr, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, nullptr,
    0, &featureLevel, (UINT)(1), D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &m_pDevice, 0, &m_pDeviceContext);

return hResult;
}
HRESULT CreateDXGIDevice()
{
return m_pDevice->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&m_pDXGIDevice));;
}
HRESULT CreateCompatibleTexture()
{
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC textureDescription;
textureDescription.Width = m_OutputDuplicationDescription.ModeDesc.Width;
textureDescription.Height = m_OutputDuplicationDescription.ModeDesc.Height;
textureDescription.Format = m_OutputDuplicationDescription.ModeDesc.Format;
textureDescription.ArraySize = 1;
textureDescription.BindFlags = 0;
textureDescription.MiscFlags = 0;
textureDescription.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
textureDescription.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
textureDescription.MipLevels = 1;
textureDescription.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
textureDescription.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;

return m_pDevice->CreateTexture2D(&textureDescription, 0, &m_pCompatibleTexture);
}
HRESULT CreateDXGIOutput()
{
return m_pDXGIAdapter->EnumOutputs((UINT)(0), &m_pDXGIOutput);
}
HRESULT DuplicateOutput()
{
return m_pDXGIOutput1->DuplicateOutput(m_pDevice, &m_pOutputDuplication);
}
HRESULT CreateDXGIAdapter()
{
return m_pDXGIDevice->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIAdapter), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&m_pDXGIAdapter));
}
HRESULT CreateDXGIOutput1()
{
return m_pDXGIOutput->QueryInterface(__uuidof(m_pDXGIOutput1), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&m_pDXGIOutput1));
}

HRESULT GetOutputDescription()
{
return m_pDXGIOutput->GetDesc(&m_OutputDescription);
}

HRESULT CaptureScreen()
{
DXGI_OUTDUPL_FRAME_INFO FrameInfo;
IDXGIResource* DesktopResource = nullptr;

HRESULT hResult = m_pOutputDuplication->AcquireNextFrame(9999, &FrameInfo, &DesktopResource);

if (FAILED(hResult))
{
    return hResult;
}

hResult = DesktopResource->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&m_pDesktopTexture));

DesktopResource->Release();
DesktopResource = nullptr;

if (FAILED(hResult))
{
    return hResult;
}

m_pDeviceContext->CopyResource(m_pCompatibleTexture, m_pDesktopTexture);
m_pDeviceContext->Map(m_pCompatibleTexture, D3D11CalcSubresource(0, 0, 0), D3D11_MAP_READ_WRITE, 0, &m_mappedResource);
BYTE* sptr = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(m_mappedResource.pData);
m_pDeviceContext->Unmap(m_pCompatibleTexture, 0);

m_pOutputDuplication->ReleaseFrame();

return hResult;
}
int main()
{
HRESULT hr;
hr = CreateD3DDevice();
std::cout << hr << std::endl;
hr = CreateDXGIDevice();
std::cout << hr << std::endl;
hr = CreateDXGIAdapter();
std::cout << hr << std::endl;
hr = CreateDXGIOutput();
std::cout << hr << std::endl;
hr = GetOutputDescription();
std::cout << hr << std::endl;
hr = CreateDXGIOutput1();
std::cout << hr << std::endl;
hr = DuplicateOutput();
std::cout << hr << std::endl;
m_pOutputDuplication->GetDesc(&m_OutputDuplicationDescription);
hr = CaptureScreen();
std::cout << hr << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you check all HRESULT and enable and use the DirectX Debug layer. https://walbourn.github.io/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks/ & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-devices-layers

Comment: In addition to the links @SimonMourier provided, see [Programming DirectX with COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/prog-dx-with-com) and [Anatomy of Direct3D 11 Create Device](https://walbourn.github.io/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device/)

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me. But AcquireNextFrame receives the next image only after 20 ms, is it possible to somehow speed up this process?